# How to plot damped sine/cos wave?

Tags: math-software

I have a table of xy data which needs to be modelled using a damped sine wave. What Windows program (preferably free or trial) can do that for me?

There are over 600 data points per model.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to fit a "damped" wave (what is your definition of a damped wave, anyway?) to your points, know that fitting oscillatory functions can be a difficult problem. You might want to post a scatter plot of your points here...

Answer (score 2):

I happen to think that R is a great, free piece of software for plotting pretty much any set of data points you want. To be fair, I haven't used it in about a year, but I expect that it will suit your needs. You can find more about it http://www.r-project.org/ .